# How do I show that we can't write $N=114^n-1$ as sum of $3$ squares for all natural number $n>2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, congruences

I run some computations in wolfram alpha, I see that we can't write :$$N=114^n-1$$ as sum of $3$ squares, then Hop someone who can show me how I do  prove that we can't write $N=114^n-1$ as sum of $3$ squares for all natural number $n>2$?

Note : I have tried to use reccurrence demonstration but it's seems not work

Thank you for any help

Comment: What computations did you carry out on Wolfram|Alpha?  Can you reproduce them for us?

Comment: just giving some values for n and it's seems working

Comment: @zeraouliarafik "Some" values for n? Are we talking 3 here? 1000?

Comment: I tried `Table[SquaresR[3, 114^n - 1], {n, 25}]`, got $96$ and $864$ and then a bunch of zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as soon as $n \geq 3,$ we know that $$ 114^n = 2^n \; 3^n \; 19^n \equiv 0 \pmod 8.  $$ as a result,
$$ 114^n -1 \equiv 7 \pmod 8,  $$
and cannot be the sum of three squares, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem

Comment: thank you then, i'm a right , but how to prove this , is the proof that what you cited ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, I guess English is not your first language. It also appears that you do not have any beginning books in number theory. Perhaps you know French? There should be many books in French, and some in Arabic or Berber, that would cover this sort of material, congruences, sums of squares, and so on. Maybe you could at least borrow some books. Learning directly from websites may seem quick, but important material is not carefully covered on the computer; that is where books come in.

Comment: no, english is not a problem for me , just i'm doing small research about this problem :http://mathoverflow.net/q/211567/74330  , and in the fact you are included by Gerhard pasem for this problem as BBC

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, yes, I got the copy from Gerhard

Comment: i'm willing to listen for your advices , but the problem is very complicated and i think it's equivalent to Riemann Hypothesis

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$114^1-1=2^2+3^2+10^2.$$

Comment: sorry , for n>2

Comment: I didn't get attention to 1 and 2

Comment: now , it's seems working

Answer (score 1):

The someone you are looking for is Legendre. Google would have found him for you. See [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem)

Comment: ok,thank you for observation

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Working mod 4, show that if $114^n-1$ were the sum of 3 squares, then those squares would all be odd.  Working mod 8, show that there are no solutions.